# Bi-dimensional list, keep only lines with unique values on column

Tags: python

I have a list like:

```
[['A','B','1'],  
 ['A','D','2'],  
 ['F','B','1'],  
 ['K','B','1'],  
 ['M','D','2'],  
 ['G','H','3']  
]
```

I would like to keep only the lines where 'column' 2 contains unique values.
And more specific, the new 'matrix' should only have the last two columns.

result:

```
[    
 ['B','1'],  
 ['D','2'],  
 ['H','3']  
]
```

There are more than 1.000.000 lines, and column 2 contains strings of 48 digits, so a fast way to do it is preferable.

Thank you,
Tom

I tried:

```
matrixData=[['A','B','1'],['A','D','2'],['F','B','1'],['K','B','1'],['M','D','2'],['G','H','3']]  
uniqueCol2=[]  
uniqueCol3=[]  
for line in matrixData:  
    if line[1] not in uniqueCol2:  
        uniqueCol2.append(line[1])  
        uniqueCol3.append(line[2])  
print uniqueCol2  
print uniqueCol3
```

result

```
['B','D','H']  
['1','2','3']
```

this gives me two lists, in the end i need the sum of uniqueCol3, but since there are more then 1.000.000 lines and probably because strings contains 48 digits it takes a lot of time to check `if line[1] not in uniqueCol2:`.

Comment: Have you tried anything? I don't quite understand how `'B'` and `'D'` are considered unique in your example.

Comment: This is a really generic question.. What language are you using? What have you already tried doing?

Comment: what is the rule to choose the unique lines?

Comment: What should be the output, if `['A', 'B', '2']` is one of the input items?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along the lines of:

```
 def crop(input_matrix):
     output_matrix = []
     unique = set() # Tracks unique 2nd column entries
     for row in input_matrix:
         if row[1] not in unique: # If second column is unique, add the row slice to the output matrix
            output_matrix.append(row[1:2])
            unique.add(row[1]) # Add that value to unique entries we've found so far
     return output_matrix
```

`set` is **O(1)** to search through, so it's as efficient as you're going to get from that aspect. The total complexity of this is therefore **O(n)** with the number of rows in the input matrix, which I think is as efficient as you're going to get unless there's some information you can use to predict what rows will be non-unique.

You can absolutely code-golf this down to two lines of code with a list comprehension, but I didn't for clarity's sake